# How do i make my discord bot shows in chat like "Bot is typing"

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm new to the field of discord bots, I had an idea and it's that, I want to make my bot show "bot is typing..." status before the bot send any messages.
I simply want it to looks like real typing you know? And I guess that will look better than just sending the messages immediately.

BTW, I'm using Discord.py Rewrite

Thanks for your help in advance!

---

[example for what I want the bot to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Z0r.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`async with channel.typing()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.typing)

If you are unfamiliar with the `with` statement, it is a way of wrapping a codeblock in a statement, which does something at the start of the code block and the end of the codeblock.

Example:

```py
import asyncio

async def on_message(message):
     if message.startswith('ping'):
          async with message.channel.typing():
               await asyncio.sleep(1)
               await message.channel.send('pong')
```